# Surely $\Rightarrow$ almost surely?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question that maybe is silly, but important.

In our reading, we had (concerning the Lebesgue integral):

> > Let $f,g\geq 0$ be measurable. Then:
> >     $$
> > f\leq g\mbox{ a.s. }\Rightarrow\int f\ d\mu\leq\int g\ d\mu.~~(*)
> > $$

Now I have two integrable functions $f,g$ with values in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and my question is, if then for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ it is 
$$
\int\lvert \alpha f+\beta g\rvert\leq\int(\lvert\alpha\rvert\cdot\vert f\rvert+\vert\beta\rvert\cdot\lvert g\rvert)\ d\mu.
$$

Because $\alpha f+\beta g$ is measurable, it is $\vert\alpha f+\beta g\rvert$ and this is a non-negative measurable function. Moreover it is

$\lvert \alpha f+\beta g\rvert\leq\lvert\alpha f\rvert+\vert\beta g\rvert=\lvert\alpha\rvert\cdot\vert f\rvert+\vert\beta\rvert\cdot\lvert g\rvert$.

I think then I can apply (*). Because the conditions are fullfilled and even not almost surely but surely.

Right?

Comment: right, you can do it

Comment: Do you know what it means that a given property holds "almost surely"?

Comment: Isn't the proper wording in this context (of measure theory) "$\mu$-almost everywhere"?

Comment: Yes, sometimes we say that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a property that holds everywhere also holds $\mu$-almost everywhere. This follows straight from the definition.